# Unable to install SP1 for Visual Studio 2010 express Windows Phone 7 in Windows 8?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, async-await, async-ctp

I am installing on Windows 8 OS Visual Studio 2010 express for Windows Phone with Async CTP for that I have installed Visual Studio 2010 express for Windows Phone as shown below:
[image]

I am now installing Windows Phone SP1 from link http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=23691

But it is always giving me error as shown below:
[image]

How should I use Async CTP. My goal is to use Async and Await in Windows Phone 7.1 application with Visual Studio 2010 and not in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: The Async CTP had a number of known (and not always documented) bugs, many of which had to do with installation. This always made setting up a new machine with Async CTP problematic. So even if you got SP1 installed, you would probably not be able to get the Async CTP installed. But you don't need to, anyway, since VS2012 will support `async` on WP if you install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. There is no reason *not* to upgrade to VS2012 in your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Service Pack you try to install is not provided for Windows 8:

```
Supported Operating Systems: 
Windows 7, Windows Server 2003 R2 (32-Bit x86), Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 editions, 
Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008 R2, 
Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista Service Pack 2, 
Windows XP Service Pack 3.
```

The second bad news: "Using async/await without .NET Framework 4.5" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx

In order to use await you need two components:

- **Visual Studio 2012**
- Some specific .NET APIs

Maybe you want to use VS Express 2012 or the trial Version of VS 2012: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-editions instead of VS2010?

The new VS 2012 language and library features are 
available in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop, 
**including the async and await keywords** in Visual Basic and C#, C++ AMP, 
and improvements to C++ 11 Standards conformance.

**You can use Express for Windows Desktop with 
your Visual Basic and C# applications to target both .NET 4.0 and 4.5.**